SetWindowPlacement makes a modal form to freeze
In the OnCreate event of a modal form, I use SetWindowPlacement() to restore the form's size and position that was previously saved. It works OK in a non-modal form, but it totally freezes on a modal form after a few seconds it appears.
Form1 is calling Form2 as modal.
I cannot use SetWindowPlacement() in the OnShow event because we get the exception:

class EInvalidOperation with message 'Cannot change Visible in OnShow or OnHide'.

The expecting result is to show a modal form on the last location before it was closed. SetWindowPlacement() is the right function to use since it works OK on multiple monitors, even if one of the monitors is unplugged after the location was saved. If we don't consider this possibility, the form will just appear off-screen (hidden).
This is the short piece of code:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
  Form2.ShowModal;
  FreeAndNil(form2);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Hard coded paremeters to make it simple
  RestoreFormPosition(self, 100, 200, 301, 463);
end;

procedure TForm2.RestoreFormPosition(WhichForm: TForm; const pTop, pLeft, pHeight, pWidth: Integer);
var
  recWndPlmt : TWindowPlacement;
begin
  WhichForm.Position := poDesigned;

  recWndPlmt.Length:= SizeOf(TWindowPlacement);
  //GetWindowPlacement(WhichForm.Handle, @recWndPlmt);

  recWndPlmt.rcNormalPosition.Top      := pTop;
  recWndPlmt.rcNormalPosition.Left     := pLeft;
  recWndPlmt.rcNormalPosition.Height   := pHeight;
  recWndPlmt.rcNormalPosition.Width    := pWidth;
  recWndPlmt.showCMD:= SW_SHOWNORMAL; //1;

  SetWindowPlacement(WhichForm.Handle, @recWndPlmt);
end;


I would not do this in the OnCreate event. I would override the virtual CreateWnd() method and do it from there instead after calling the inherited method that creates the HWND. Or, even override the virtual CreateParams() or CreateWindowHandle() method to apply the desired position and dimensions while the HWND is being created.

Hi Remy. I moved RestoreFormPosition to CreateParams event. It produces an stack overflow exception, because it enters multiple times.
From CreateWnd and CreateWindowHandle, the function RestoreFormPosition is doing nothing, the parameters for size are being ignored since the form has the default dimensions as in design time. It freezes in all the cases anyway.
But I notice that these 3 events are executed before OnCreate. I might be doing something wrong.

I declared the 3 events in the form public section:
procedure CreateWnd; override;
procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
procedure CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams); override;

I wasn't suggesting you call RestoreFormPosition() inside of CreateParams() or CreateWindowHandle(). That obviously wouldn't work since there is no HWND available in those methods, as the HWND is in the act of being created when those methods are called. But you can change the X/Y/Width/Height values of the TCreateParams that is used to create the HWND.

In any case, I can reproduce the problem in Delphi 12.2, so it is not limited to just 10.2 as you have tagged.

From CreateParams event, after inherited, the var parameters changes are ignored. No changes on the form afterwards. I hard-coded the values.
Params.X:= 100;
Params.Y:= 200;
Params.Height:= 301;
Params.Width:= 463;

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I don't know the root cause, but I can reproduce the problem in Delphi 12.2.  For whatever reason, using SetWindowPlacement() in this manner causes the Form's window to become disabled deep inside the VCL before the window is shown on-screen.  In the OnShow event, IsWindowEnabled() returns False, whereas it returns True if SetWindowPlacement() is not used.
I have opened a bug ticket with Embarcadero:
RSS-1915: Calling SetWindowPlacement() on a modal form disables the window
Until Embarcadero fixes this, calling EnableWindow() in the OnShow event solves the problem:
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnableWindow(Handle, True);
end;

Using the Form's SetBounds() method instead of SetWindowPlacement() also avoids the problem:
//SetWindowPlacement(WhichForm.Handle, @recWndPlmt);
WhichForm.SetBounds(pLeft, pTop, pWidth, pHeight);


Thanks Remy for your help! EnableWindow() made the trick.

I have chosen SetWindowPlacement() because the form is restored properly in a secondary monitor, if that was the last saved position of the form. This is the expected behavior.
Also, if the secondary monitor is unplugged, (pLeft becoming off-screen), SetWindowPlacement() adjust the coordinates so that the window is always visible anyway.
(From the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowplacement)

But with SetBounds(), it's always restoring to the main monitor, ignoring if pLeft position was pointing to somewhere in the second monitor and even if the second monitor is still plugged.

You can use the Form's MakeFullyVisible() method to display the Form on a specific monitor if the desired monitor is not available in Screen.Monitors
